# How do I reclaim my Clash of Clans account?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I got Clash if Clans on my laptop and started a village. Then a couple of weeks later it said "This app was not installed properly". So I went and redownloaded it but it started a new account. How do I reclaim my old one back?